# Dynamic excel hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

Hello at the moment I currently have code that generates a seried of hyperlinks in a table that when clicked reference back to a cell on a different sheet contained in the workbook book. See code below.

```
Report.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Report.Cells(LineNum, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="Data!A" & (Counter - 1), TextToDisplay:="Link to Data"
```

The variable counter is the cell in which the data I am linking to is located and Data is the sheet it is contained in. Report is the worksheet to which I am writing the hyperlinks too.

The issue that I am encountering is that when data is either removed or added in the "Data" sheet the hyperlink in the "report" sheet will then link to the wrong cell thus rendering it useless. So to conclude is their a way to generate a dynamic hyperlink that changes based on edits (only line removals not column removal) to endure the hyperlinks link back to the correct data?  Thank you for you help.

Full while loop as requested

```
DaysInCombo = 0
DaysInYear = DateSerial(YearA + 1, 1, 1) - DateSerial(YearA, 1, 1)


ExtraColNumber = Data.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1

UltimateCount = Data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Do While Data.Cells(Counter, 4).Value <> ""

'Check if at new position the address or meter number has changed
If Data.Cells(Counter, 4).Value <> CurrentAddress Or Data.Cells(Counter, 11).Value <> CurrentMeterNumber Then
    'check num days to determine if there is an exception to be considered
    If DaysInCombo = DaysInYear Then
        Debug.Print "Good:       " & CurrentAddress
    Else
        Debug.Print "Bad:        " & CurrentAddress & " - " & DaysInCombo & " days - SN: " & CurrentMeterNumber
        'compare meter number against the known lists
        'if meter exists within the known lists then make note and place into a string
        ExceptionStr = ""
        ReasonStr = ""
        TimeRangeStr = ""
        'Data.Cells(Counter, 36).Value

        'Compare against Meter Removal List
            CheckCounter = 2
            Do While MeterRemoval.Cells(CheckCounter, 1).Value <> ""
                If CurrentMeterNumber = MeterRemoval.Cells(CheckCounter, 10).Value Or _
                    Right(CurrentMeterNumber, 8) = MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 10).Value Or _
                    (InStr(1, CurrentAddress, MeterRemoval.Cells(CheckCounter, 6).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 And _
                    MeterRemoval.Cells(CheckCounter, 6).Value <> "") Then
                    Debug.Print "Success"
                    ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "Meter Found on the Meter Removal list"
                    ReasonStr = ReasonStr & "Removed meter"
                End If
                CheckCounter = CheckCounter + 1
            Loop

        'Compare against Meter Install List
            CheckCounter = 2
            Do While MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value <> ""
                If CurrentMeterNumber = MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    Right(CurrentMeterNumber, 8) = MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    InStr(1, CurrentAddress, MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 3).Value & " " & MeterInstall.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    Debug.Print "Success"
                    ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "New Meter Installation"
                    ReasonStr = ReasonStr & "New meter"
                End If
                CheckCounter = CheckCounter + 1
            Loop

        'Compare against Meter Replace List
            CheckCounter = 2
            Do While MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value <> ""
                If CurrentMeterNumber = MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    Right(CurrentMeterNumber, 8) = MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    CurrentMeterNumber = MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 5).Value Or _
                    Right(CurrentMeterNumber, 8) = MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 5).Value Or _
                    InStr(1, CurrentAddress, MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 3).Value & " " & MeterReplace.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    Debug.Print "Success"
                    ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "Replaced Meter"
                    ReasonStr = ReasonStr & "Replaced meter"
                End If
                CheckCounter = CheckCounter + 1
            Loop

        'Compare Address Against the Address change list
            CheckCounter = 2
            'needs work
            Do While AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 1).Value <> ""
                If InStr(1, CurrentAddress, AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Or _
                    (InStr(1, CurrentAddress, AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 And _
                    AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value <> "") Then
                    Debug.Print CurrentAddress
                    Debug.Print AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 1).Value
                    Debug.Print AddressChange.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value
                    Debug.Print "Success"
                    ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "The address was changed"
                    ReasonStr = ReasonStr & "Address change"
                End If
                CheckCounter = CheckCounter + 1
            Loop

        'Meter Replace NMOG
            CheckCounter = 2
            Do While MeterReplaceNMOG.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value <> ""
                If CurrentMeterNumber = MeterReplaceNMOG.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    Right(CurrentMeterNumber, 8) = MeterReplaceNMOG.Cells(CheckCounter, 4).Value Or _
                    InStr(1, CurrentAddress, MeterReplaceNMOG.Cells(CheckCounter, 3).Value & " " & MeterReplaceNMOG.Cells(CheckCounter, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                    Debug.Print "Success"

                    ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "Replaced Meter NMOG"
                    ReasonStr = ReasonStr & "Replaced meter NMOG"
                End If
                CheckCounter = CheckCounter + 1
            Loop


        'Check if an exception was found
        ExceptionFound = True
        If ExceptionStr = "" Or ReasonStr = "" Then
            ExceptionStr = "No Exception reason has been found automatically"
            ExceptionFound = False
        End If

        If DateValue(FirstDateRead) > DateValue(Format(DateSerial(YearA, 1, 1))) Then
            ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "Meter Recording Started Mid Year"
            TimeRangeStr = TimeRangeStr & "Started Mid Year"
        End If
        If DateValue(LastDateRead) < DateValue(Format(DateSerial(YearA + 1, 1, 1))) Then
            ExceptionStr = ExceptionStr & vbCrLf & "Meter Recording Ended Mid Year"
            If TimeRangeStr <> "" Then
                TimeRangeStr = TimeRangeStr & " - "
            End If
            TimeRangeStr = TimeRangeStr & "Ended Mid Year"
        End If

        ExceptionStr = DaysInCombo & " days: " & vbCrLf & ExceptionStr
        'The counter is decremented by 1 due to the logic within the loop
        Data.Cells(Counter - 1, ExtraColNumber).Value = ExceptionStr

        'Make report
        'if expection found, then use one report, else other
        If ExceptionFound = True Then
            Set Report = Report_Auto
        Else
            Set Report = Report_Manual
        End If

        'get last line of report sheet
        LineNum = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        'copy some relevant details of the location to the report and give it a link back to the location in the data.
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Link
        Report.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Report.Cells(LineNum, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="Data!A" & (Counter - 1), TextToDisplay:="Link to Data"
        'Address
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 2).Value = CurrentAddress
        'MeterSN
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 3).Value = CurrentMeterNumber
        'MeterInstall
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 4).Value = Data.Cells(Counter - 1, 13).Value
        'FirstDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 5).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 5).Value = Format(FirstDateBill, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'LastDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 6).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 6).Value = Format(LastDateBill, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'FirstDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 7).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 7).Value = Format(FirstDateRead, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'LastDate
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 8).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 8).Value = Format(LastDateRead, "dd-MMM-yy")
        'ProratedDays
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 9).Value = DaysInCombo
        'RangeText
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 10).Value = TimeRangeStr
        'ExceptionText
        Report.Cells(LineNum, 11).Value = ReasonStr
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        'clear the report value for the next iteration
        Set Report = Nothing
```

Loop

Comment: That would be based on your usage of counter. I believe your code is in some sort of a loop? Could you add that code as well?

Comment: Have you considered naming the cells and link to the names?

Comment: Luuklag I have included the full while loop as requested

Comment: Sam yes I was considering using a search or match function to locate hyperlink location. In both of these sheets there is an ID which I could use to match however I am sturggling with determing a hyperlink funtion that utilizes a match or lookup function. This is what I was looking at 
  
  =IF($C7=0,"",HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(INDIRECT(C7&"!B:B"),MATCH(A7,INDIRECT(C7&"!A:A"),0))), "Link"))

Comment: @user9730643, please minimize the code so that it only contains those parts that are essential. So where `Linenum` and `Counter` inherit their values from. The full code is hardly ever usefull, as it is just too much effort to sift through it all to determine what parts are needed. On a side note, if you want to notify somebody include an `@` before their username to ping them.

Comment: @Luuklag The variable Linenum is  a counter starting at 2 with 1 added each time the loop is performed. It serves as a way output all the data to the row after the one you just wrote. As for Counter it variable that references the the row value in the sheet "data" from which the values are being pulled. For example the install date is found in a set column but changes each row. Counter is a way to pull that row from the data sheet and input it into the new sheet.